# Rospack find error

Tags: ros-melodic, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I write question first time in this page, so please let me know if I had some mistake.
I use Autoware 1.13 in Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS Melodic, but it can't find some packages.
I already use

> source /install/setup.bash

This code is effective to find 'lidar_localizer' but not effective to find 'runtime_manager'. I should use

> roslaunch runtime_manager runtime_manager

to start the autoware. Why the source command didn't applied in runtime_manager package?
And, How can I use this package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342773/rospack-find-error/) by [kasy](https://answers.ros.org/users/51299/kasy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you're using the **release** repo when you compiled it from the source. If that is the case, then there are two options,

1. You could use Mate terminal
2. Modify ~/autoware.ai/install/runtime_manager/share/runtime_manager/scripts/run script to accommodate your terminal. In my case, I was using Terminator terminal, hence I added the following lines,

`elif [ $(which terminator) ]; then TERMINAL=terminator`

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Vicky](https://answers.ros.org/users/51355/vicky/) with karma: 16 on 2020-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0